# Renaming filenames in subdirectories

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using the following to sort out filenames.

```
    for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//remove/replace}"; done
```

How could I use this or a similar solution to recursively work through a bunch of subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, this is my favorite:

```
find <the-path> <the-criteria> | while read file; do mv $file <$file-renamed>; done
```

For instance:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" | while read file; do mv "$file" "`echo $file | sed -e 's/jpg/png/'`"; done
```

Use `sed` or whatever tool you need to build the replacement name.